# Changes in Github fork not being imported

Tags: go, github

I'm writing a MIDI parser that splits apart MIDI files and adjusts the volume on different tracks to allow for specific voice isolation to help practicing. I'm using a Go library, [EasyMIDI](https://github.com/algoGuy/EasyMIDI). However, I ran into a use case that the library didn't cover, so I forked the repo and made changes that should fix my issues in the short term.

I'm able to successfully build when using my forked Github URL in my `go.mod` and import statements, but the code changes I made aren't being reflected. I added the function `GetChannel()` to an interface, and so should see it listed as an option. When I click into the source for another function that was originally implemented, I see that my VSCode is referencing the non-forked repo when grabbing the code (see screen snippet below).

[image: VSCode Screen Snippet]

As you can see on the left, there is no `GetChannel()` function. If I click on "algo!guy" and select "!try431", I do see the changes I made and pushed to my fork. How do I get my code to recognize that I want my forked repo so I can get access to these changes I've made?

Edit: Thought I might as well throw in the `go.mod` and `go.sum` files that are generated upon a `go build`.

**go.mod**

```
module github.com/Try431/acc-midi-splitter

go 1.12

require github.com/Try431/EasyMIDI v0.0.0-20190921213858-238fe2946087
```

**go.sum**

```
github.com/Try431/EasyMIDI v0.0.0-20190921213858-238fe2946087 h1:dXDwjgIHMgL4zow9ixgTslZ3cWZHHIu3+FurDjDC6wA=
github.com/Try431/EasyMIDI v0.0.0-20190921213858-238fe2946087/go.mod h1:c/dd/WkUR9yfzjC9sPO9J0vh5TzTmE8ryAvEviTDwgg=
github.com/algoGuy/EasyMIDI v0.0.0-20180322051653-708ca39e7399 h1:f0h3xTKQjrTzAUwqMJr1TY3lk3gTK8R4v7ZjcSMiwm8=
github.com/algoGuy/EasyMIDI v0.0.0-20180322051653-708ca39e7399/go.mod h1:z6svyEeOasADFxg4gn6funK2OBjocr62B4J7ZPodCPs=
```

I've tried deleting the algoGuy lines in the `go.sum`, but obviously the lines are put back on a `go build`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a replace statement in go.mod:

```
replace original => fork
```

This should make references to the original repo in the forked source lookup from the forked repo.